# Message=Input string was not in a correct format. in c#

Tags: c#

The following exception is being thrown in the first while loop that I convert to double:

```
System.FormatException
  HResult=0x80131537
  Message=Input string was not in a correct format.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Number.ParseDouble(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
   at System.Convert.ToDouble(String value)
   at WindowsFormsApp6.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\King\source\repos\WindowsFormsApp6\WindowsFormsApp6\Form1.cs:line 52
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at WindowsFormsApp6.Program.Main() in C:\Users\King\source\repos\WindowsFormsApp6\WindowsFormsApp6\Program.cs:line 19
```

I'm not sure what I'm writing wrong or how to fix this issue. I'm reading from a csv file.  I have tested to make sure the data is being passed from variable to variable, and it is.  the data is being read by my streamreader and stored in single dimensional arrays which are being saved to a variable that I am using to compare the data points to determine all the peaks and the valleys in the dataset

This is my program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApp6
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        double firstY = 0.0;

        string testX;
        string testY;

        string[] xpoint = new string[5000];
        string[] ypoint = new string[5000];

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"D:\data.csv"))
            {
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string line = reader.ReadLine();
                    var values = line.Split(',');

                    testX = values[0];
                    testY = values[1];

                    if (firstY == 0.0)
                    {
                        firstY = Convert.ToDouble(testY);
                        Convert.ToString(testY);
                    }

                    while (Convert.ToDouble(testY) >= firstY)//where error is
                    {
                        firstY = Convert.ToDouble(testY);

                        if (firstY == Convert.ToDouble(testY))
                        {
                            break;
                        }

                        if (Convert.ToDouble(testY) < firstY)
                        {
                            listBox1.Items.Add(Convert.ToDouble(testX) + "," + firstY);

                            break;
                        }

                        break;
                    }

                    while (Convert.ToDouble(testY) < firstY)
                    {
                        firstY = Convert.ToDouble(testY);

                        if(firstY == Convert.ToDouble(testY))
                        {
                            break;
                        }

                        if (Convert.ToDouble(testY) > firstY)
                        {

                            listBox2.Items.Add(Convert.ToDouble(testX) + "," + firstY);

                            break;
                        }

                        break;
                    }

                    Convert.ToString(testX);
                    Convert.ToString(testY);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The first thing I'd do is run this in a debugger, and set it to break when that exception is thrown. Then you can look at the value that's failing to parse.

Comment: The string you are trying to convert is not a valid double value. Maybe a culture problem? check if the numbers have the correct decimal separator that matches your system language. Comma or dot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the piece of code I needed to keep the exception from being thrown (For anyone who may be receiving the same exception and unsure why) You need to put the conversion of the two variables in a "try/catch".  Like this:

```
try
{
    testX = Convert.ToDouble(values[0]);
    testX = Convert.ToDouble(values[1]);
}
catch
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your csv file there's a value that can't be converted to double.
To avoid this exception replace all your `Convert.ToDouble` with [`Double.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.1). That will return `true` if the value can be parsed to `double` or `false` if it can't.

Having said that, the rest of your code doesn't make sense.
If you look at this part, for example:

```
                while (Convert.ToDouble(testY) >= firstY)//where error is
                {
                    firstY = Convert.ToDouble(testY);

                    if (firstY == Convert.ToDouble(testY))
                    {
                        break;
                    }
```

Assuming the conversion to double was OK, your code checks if `firstY == Convert.ToDouble(testY)` - which will always return `true` since `firstY` is the result of `Convert.ToDouble(testY)`, so you break out of the loop, never entering the second loop since it's condition is `while (Convert.ToDouble(testY) < firstY)` - you should know by now they are the same value...

I'm guessing you are mixing `testY` and `testX` in your code.